# Send emal stmp office 365 : message empty

Tags: python, smtp, office365

I'm trying to send an email in Python

It's working without problem with gmail with this code :

```
import smtplib

sender = 'xxx@xxx'
receivers = ['xxx@gmail.com']
message = "hello"

try:
  smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
  smtpObj.starttls()
  smtpObj.login('xxxx@gmail.com', 'my_password')
  smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
  smtpObj.quit()
  print("okay")

except:
  print("notokay")
```

But when i use it with office 365, the email is send but the message is empty.

It's the same code but with 'smtp.office365.com:587' with my correct login and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText('hello')

msg['Subject'] = 'Urgent message'
msg['From'] = 'xxx@xxx'
msg['To'] = 'xxx@gmail.com'

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
s.starttls()
s.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'my_password')
s.sendmail('xxx@xxx', 'xxx@gmail.com', msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Try the following, it might be because you need to create a MIMEText context for the formatting to be accepted by office365.

Comment: I tried and the sendMail fail. When i try to print msg.as_string(), i have this problem : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: God it's my fault. I tried to put the list receivers in the msg['To']. Now it works fine. Thanks you !